# Как задать подключение по ssh только с определенного домена

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, openssh

У меня есть домен вида `ssh.dev.xxxxx.xxxxx.xx`, и я хочу сделать так, чтобы подключиться к серверу по ssh можно было только с этого домена и определенного порта. A-запись на домене настроена. В конечном итоге, хочу набрать у себя в терминале строчку `ssh username@ssh.dev.xxxxx.xxxxx.xx -p 9999`

Текущая конфигурация sshd_config:
[image: Текущая конфигурация sshd_config]

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/479587/restricting-ssh-to-a-specific-hostname

Comment: `sshd` работает только обслуживая клиентов с ихними секретными ключами. Ограничениями обратного ip адреса занимаются firewall-ы и роутеры. Максимум можно запретить парольный доступ. Оставить только ключи.

Answer (score 0):

> username@ssh.dev.xxxxx.xxxxx.xx -p 9999.

В данной строке вы подключаетесь не c определённого домена а на него username@remoutepc. Вам нужен статический IP на хосте с которого вы хотите подключаться, этот хост необходимо указать в  ListenAddress, такой вариант будет приближен к тому что вы хотите. Ещё более красивым и безопасным решением будет использование ключей шифрования для установки соединения, в таком варианте вы не привязаны ни к имени хоста ни к его IP (если не настроено обратного)

Что касается соеденения по именам, то с точки зрения сетей такой вариант не поддерживается, любое соединение это TCP/IP, по этому существуют DNS сервера которые резольвят DNS-имена в IP адреса. Теоретически конечно можно передавать имя ПК как мета данные и проверять его на валидность, но выглядит это странно и не безопасно.